# Is there any solution to following error "Object name contains restricted error"?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I am trying to create a duplicate table using following query:

```
CREATE TABLE folder.table1
 AS
 SELECT * FROM folder.original_table;

CREATE TABLE folder.table1
 AS folder.original_table WITH DATA;
```

However, after execution i am getting "Object name has invalid characters" and i don't know which object it is talking about. Please tell me how to trace the error to the particular object?

I have read on teradata docs link that i need to contact to Database Administrator, but i don't want to do that. Please suggest some alternative solutions.

Comment: Only the 2nd Create will create an exact copy, the 1st will drop all indexes and constraints. Regarding the error, it's strange because a table name violating the rules should not exist. Check the table/column names if they're double quoted and contain strange characters.

Comment: And if you pasted from Excel or something, paste your SQL in text editor first, to make sure you don't have any funky hidden characters, maybe.